# Getting index by name

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently on my first somewhat To Do App and i have trouble with deleting things. I dont actually understand how to properly get the value to search it by index.

```
import json
import tkinter as tk


class JsonArrayStore:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.__load()

    def __load(self):
        try:
            f = open(self.filename, 'r')
            self.info = json.load(f)
            f.close()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.info = []

    def __save(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.info, f)

    def append(self, data, force_save=True):
        self.info.append(data)
        if force_save:
            self.__save()

    def remove(self, index, force_save=True):
        del self.info[index]
        if force_save:
            self.__save()


class ToDoGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Don't Forget!")
        self.geometry('600x400+200+100')
        self.configure(bg='#eae5e1')

        self.logo_bg = tk.Frame(master=self, height=20, width=3000)
        self.logo_bg.pack()

        self.logo_text = tk.Label(master=self.logo_bg, bg = '#599D9C',
                                  width=3000,
                                  text="Kelpie's To Do App!",
                                  font=('Impact', 45), fg='white')
        self.logo_text.pack()

        self.add_button_frame = tk.Frame(master=self, bg='#eae5e1')
        self.add_button_frame.pack(fill='x')
        self.label_border = tk.Label(master=self.add_button_frame, bg='#eae5e1',
                                     bd=12, width='500')
        self.label_border.pack()

        self.add_btn = tk.Button(master=self.label_border, text='Add Task!', command=self.on_button)
        self.add_btn.pack(side='right', padx=10)

        # Later: Add a placeholder func
        self.add_text = tk.Entry(master=self.label_border)
        self.add_text.insert(0, '')
        self.add_text.pack(side='left', padx=10)

        # Frames for tasks
        self.task_frame = tk.Frame(master=self)
        self.task_frame.pack()

        # load from json file
        a = JsonArrayStore('test1.json')
        for i in a.info:
            add_task_label = tk.Label(master=self, bg='red', text=f'{i}')
            add_task_label.pack()
            delete_btn = tk.Button(self, bg='green', text='Delete', command=self.del_btn)
            delete_btn.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        a = JsonArrayStore('test1.json')
        a.append(self.add_text.get())
        task = tk.Label(master=self, bg='red', text=f'{self.add_text.get()}')
        task.pack()
        delete_btn = tk.Button(self, bg='green', text='Delete', command=self.del_btn)
        delete_btn.pack()

    def del_btn(self):
        a = JsonArrayStore('test1.json')
        x = a.info.index()



test = ToDoGUI()
test.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is quite nice.  However, it looks like you store the data to a JSON file and are trying to read the JSON file.  But the file contents are a `list` and not JSON format...  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: You should probably store the data as a CSV and then read this quickly with the `CSV` module or the `pandas` module (`pandas.read_csv()`). This way you would retrieve the list quickly...

Comment: I had an idea that later on i will add groups of projects and use key in a dict as a name to Group. But now yeah, i have list in my json

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using `enumerate` to get the index in the for-loop and then using a lambda as command for the delete button which stores the index. Roughly:

```
        for idx, i in enumerate(a.info):
            add_task_label = tk.Label(master=self, bg='red', text=f'{i}')
            add_task_label.pack()
            delete_btn = tk.Button(self, bg='green', text='Delete', command=lambda idx=idx: self.del_btn(idx))
            delete_btn.pack()

...

    def del_btn(self, idx):
```